# Uno Flyout with Android Immersive mode

Tags: uno-platform

In my [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/) app on Android with immersive mode enabled, when a MenuFlyout is opened, it exits the immersive mode.

Any idea to keep the immersive mode when a flyout is opened ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, as of Uno.UI 2.2.0, the Android default is to open flyouts using native popups.

To change this behavior, you can use this property by adding this line in AndroidApplication constructor:

```cs
Uno.UI.FeatureConfiguration.Popup.UseNativePopup = false;
```

This will force Uno to use a full XAML panel to display popups.

It is [defined here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/8d0d5960a2622909e97be8f1e87e504a64faf584/src/Uno.UI/FeatureConfiguration.cs#L161).

Comment: Thanks for the anwser Jerome,

With Uno.UI 2.2, I keep the immersive mode but my flyout doesn't work anymore due to this [bug](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/3012).

With Uno.UI version 2.1.39, I tried 
`Uno.UI.FeatureConfiguration.Style.UseUWPDefaultStyles = true;` and `Uno.UI.FeatureConfiguration.Popup.UseNativePopup = false;` but it doesn't work, it always use the native popups and I lose the immersive mode.

I'm going to wait the fix for [issue 3012](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/3012).